# React Context Error When Consuming Multiple Context Value

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am getting error while consuming multiple react contexts. But my instructor had the same code that I am learning from youtube.

```
import React from "react";
import { UserContext, ChannelContext} 
from "../../App";

const E = () => {
return <div>
<p>How to consume multiple contexts</p>
<UserContext.Consumer>
    {user =>{
            return (
                <ChannelContext.Consumer>
                    {channel =>{
                            return (<div>
                User Context value {user} and {channel}
            </div>)
                        }
                    }
                </ChannelContext.Consumer>
            )
        }
    }
</UserContext.Consumer>
<p>First step is to create context</p>
<p>Second step is to wrap by provider</p>
<p>third step is to consume</p>
</div>;
};

export default E;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a simple mistake of not writting Provider for one of the context.

I have written

```
<UserContext.Provider value={"Vishwas"}>
  <ChannelContext value={"codevolution"}>
    <C/>
    </ChannelContext>
  </UserContext.Provider>
```

then I changed it to

```
<UserContext.Provider value={"Vishwas"}>
  <ChannelContext.Provider value={"codevolution"}>
    <C/>
    </ChannelContext.Provider>
  </UserContext.Provider>
```

Now It is working fine :)